# Cannot set the property value for JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId in weblogic, JMS, java

Tags: java, jms, arrays, object-properties

I want to send a message to a JMS Queue, and I want to set an object property:

```
tMessage.setObjectProperty("JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId", bytes); //bytes is a byte array value
```

But I am getting an exception for this row:

```
tMessage.setObjectProperty("JMS_IBM_MQMD_MsgId", toByteArray((phone+"IBM").toCharArray()));
```

Why cannot I set byte array to this property? I saw some example, and everyone sets bytearray, but I am getting exception:

```
weblogic.jms.common.MessageFormatException: [JMSClientExceptions:055123]Invalid property value, [B@48647dd0
```

Why? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: @victorio can you post some sample code to set message I am facing issue with setting message id here is the link for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889361/how-to-set-message-id-for-ibm-mq-using-java-program/52890449?noredirect=1#comment92764464_52890449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [setObjectProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html):

> The setObjectProperty method accepts values of class Boolean, Byte,
>   Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double, and String. An attempt to use any
>   other class must throw a JMSException.

So it does not accept `ByteArray`.
`setObjectProperty` accepts `Object` so you don't get compile error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest having a look at one of the samples in the WMQ installation - called SimpleWMQMDWrite.java

This does use setObjectProperty as follows:

```
  // Generate a custom message id
  byte[] customMessageId = new byte[24];
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    // Hex-string 010203040506070801020304050607080102030405060708
    customMessageId[i] = (byte) ((i % 8) + 1);
  }

  // Write to MQMD.MsgId via JMS_IBM_MQMD_MSGID message property
  message.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_MSGID, customMessageId);
```

The error message you've included though doesn't look much like a WMQ JMS error message more WebLogic, wonder if that has wrapped the message object and is doing some additional checking?

M.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can transform your hex string to byte array using `com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.Utils.hexToBytes(yourHexString)`